# Get Number from Text Block

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have this block of HTML:

```
<div class="cart">
    <a href="/4S101W.html"><b>Gray T-shirt</b></a><br>
    Size:M<br>
    Style:1722322<br>
    <div>Qty:2</div><div>Price: $14.95</div>
<div>
```

How can I retrieve the style number, in this case, 1722322, from the above block of HTML?

I was trying

```
console.log(jQuery('div.cart:contains("Style")').html().split('<br>'));
```

But it's returns the whole block.

Comment: make sure that the html you're pulling out of the DOM doesn't have `<br />` or whatever instead of just `<br>`.

Comment: Are you able to modify the HTML here to give the `Style` and `Size` values a span with an ID? This would clean up your HTML and make this trivial.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to modify the HTML. That was my first thought, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
var divcontent=$('div.cart').text();

var arr=divcontent.split('Style:');
var styleValue = arr[1].split(':')[0];
alert(parseInt(styleValue));//parseInt extracts number from string array element.
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ssfdh7zg/)

Comment: I can't use that as I'm not guaranteed that "Qty" will follow. I have to be able to extract the style number no matter the other contents.

Comment: There are several good answers here but this is the one I ended up using. Thank you to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve the relevant textNode and parse it to number, e.g:

```
var num = +$('.cart').contents().filter(function(){
  return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf('Style:') > -1
}).get(0).nodeValue.trim().replace('Style:','');
```

```js
var num = +$('.cart').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf('Style:') > -1
}).get(0).nodeValue.trim().replace('Style:', '');

console.log(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart">
  <a href="/4S101W.html"><b>Gray T-shirt</b></a>
  <br>Size:M
  <br>Style:1722322
  <br>
  <div>Qty:2</div>
  <div>Price: $14.95</div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about Regex?

```js
console.log(
  
  ($('.cart').text()).match(/(?:Style:)(\d+)/)[1]
  
 );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart">
    <a href="/4S101W.html"><b>Gray T-shirt</b></a><br>
    Size:M<br>
    Style:1722322<br>
    <div>Qty:2</div><div>Price: $14.95</div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try....

```
document.querySelector('div.cart').textContent.split('Style:')[1].split('\n')[0]
```